# Phase/Gain margin measurements for current mode boost regulator

Tags: dc-dc-converter, boost, phase-margin

I'm looking for where to place a sense resistor in the feedback path of a current mode boost regulator with a layout similar to the one in the picture. Should I place in on the FBL or FBH trace?[image]

Comment: FBL senses voltage and FBH-FBL senses current. I suggest you measure Stability Margin with Nyquist Plot instead by driving output with AC current sweep and measure impedance vector as voltage. Bode plots are prone to errors with higher order effects when correlating with Load Step response and should not be used.

Comment: If you add a small 10-50 ohm resistor in series with FBH, inject your signal across it, then measure channel B at the junction of the new resistor with Rfb, and channel A at the junction of the new resistor and the FBH pin on IC1 you will have the control to output (voltage to current) transfer function, assuming you use a small signal excitation it should be a reasonable approximation.  For complete stability analysis you should still do load transient testing, sweeping the frequency across the BW of the converter.

Comment: Stability Margin calculations using  non invasive output impedance tests by injecting swept frequency current source signal to measure voltage ripple, correlates perfectly with Step load response whereas Bode Plots do not. THis must be repeated at different step loads, directions and min/max values. But marketting specs are often gleaned for better results. like 50~100%

Comment: The question in the title does not match the question in the body.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking for where to place a sense resistor in the feedback path of a current mode boost regulator with a layout similar to the one in the picture.

There already are all the current sense resistors you need: \$R_{CS}\$ and \$R_{FB}\$.

The former senses the switch current, the latter senses the output (LED) current.

The differential voltage across those resistors is proportional to the product of the current flowing through them and their resistance, expressed in Amperes and Ohms, respectively.

So, all you need for an evaluation is an instrumentation amplifier to gain these differential signals up a bit, and you can then use say a modern digital scope to get various closed-loop responses. You can also use a network analyzer, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Of high importance is how the sense-lines will be trashed, either by magnetic switching fields or by fast-slewing electric fields.

What if you had 1pF of coupling from drain of the FET, to either of the sense lines? Will you have stability? Or a chaotic system?